# Getting non Facebook friends to like my page

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

1. Can my non Facebook friends like my page?
2. Can I invite people to like my page that are not friends on my personal Facebook page? I don’t want some people to be my friend but I want them to like the page.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, people who are not Facebook-friends of your personal profile are allowed to Like a Facebook page that you administer, and thus become a Fan of that page.

I do not think that you can personally invite them to do so, through Facebook.

But you can do things like:

- Put a message to "Like our page on Facebook" onto your website, or into an email that you send out.
- Put a "Please like us" message somewhere on the page itself

More subtly, you can use the Page (not your personal profile) to like other Pages, and the contribute to discussions on the other Pages' walls:   this will cause some of the people reading those pages to look at your Page, and perhaps they may Like it.

Answer (score -1):

The best way that I have found to get others to Like your page is just place a  link to your Facebook page in lots of places. I have been surfing the Internet finding places to invite others to my Page.

Example:

> Please Like my Page and I will Like your Page in Return Thanks [Page URL]