# Getting people who liked another Facebook business page to like mine?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I have created a business page for my restaurant. My boss's wife has nearly 5,000 people who like her business page. Is there a way to "invite" all of the people who like her page to like my page?

Comment: Related: [Getting non Facebook friends to like my page](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/48686/354)

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way to do so. Some other ways are:

You can ask to your boss's wife to promote your page from her page. If she can post a status to ask to all fans to like your page by giving your page link.

Or

You can create an ad called `Custom Audience`. It can be done by using email addresses, phone numbers, Facebook user IDs or app user IDs.

**Custom Audience:** Use email addresses, phone numbers, Facebook user IDs or app user IDs to create and save audiences you'd like to show your ads to. [Learn more about Custom Audiences](https://www.facebook.com/business/a/custom-audiences).

So you can use boss's wife page fan's email ids, phone numbers or Facebook user ids to target them.

See the [targeting options](https://www.facebook.com/business/help/717368264947302).
See more details about [Audience Targeting Options](https://www.facebook.com/business/help/633474486707199).